# How to perform action when streaming song completed?

Tags: android, video, stream

I'm using this code for video streaming, and it's working fine. When a song is finished, it should return back on my home page, like the `Mediaplayer.setOnCompletion` method.

```
VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
mc.setAnchorView(videoView);
mc.setMediaPlayer(videoView);
Uri video = Uri.parse(stream_url);

videoView.setMediaController(mc);
videoView.setVideoURI(video);
videoView.start();
```

How can I do this with `MediaController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`VideoView.setOnCompletionListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView.html#setOnCompletionListener%28android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener%29):

> Register a callback to be invoked when the end of a media file has
>   been reached during playback.